# How can I prevent an exterior duct from rusting?

Tags: hvac, rust

The exterior ductwork leading to the AC condenser is collecting water and beginning to rust. The obvious solution is to replace the duct work, but I am having problems finding someone to do that work. Is there another solution that I am not thinking of? I thought of creating some type of cover for that area but not sure if that would work. Looking for some creative solutions that could be done in a day or two.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too late to preserve this duct. It looks like the metal is corroded to a substantial depth. Once the zinc coating (galvanization) is compromised it'll continue to rust. You could try a spray or brush-on coating, but you're unlikely to cover all vulnerable surfaces well enough to stop the inevitable.

This should be a simple connector duct with no mechanical hardware inside. I would replace it with aluminum or stainless, or simply replace it with new galvanized.

- Disable the unit.
- Remove the sheet metal screws.
- Move the unit slightly to allow clearance, and lift out the plenum.
- Temporarily cover the opening to stop pests.
- Take it to an HVAC shop and ask them to reproduce it.
- Reinstall.

Once you do that, and depending on what material you choose, it may make sense to construct a simple cover. It's difficult to keep things dry outside and near the ground, though, so I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

"[Rust Converter.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_converter)" If you haven't rusted right through yet, that stuff converts rust to not-rust, and then you can get back to trying to keep the water from collecting there.